# Android system fonts and other fonts and dyslexia

Tags: system, system-apps, operating-system, accessibility, fonts

I would like to know whether Android fonts are optimized for dyslexia. Because, to my understanding, dyslexia users read better when specific fonts that have gaps and unevennesses in the spacing and shape of each letter are used.

I wonder whether the current Robot fonts use this (and if not, whether there is a system setting for dyslexia users).

Thanks.